¿Sabe alguien cual es la diferencia entre estas 2 funciones para convertir la imagen a escala de grises?
De las dos funciones que presento, los valores de la función es lo único que cambia para hacer cambios en las imágenes contenidas en los picturebox.
La pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Qué diferencia hay entre poner una u otra función para cambiar a grises?
Public Sub ConvertirAGrises(ByVal Imagen As PictureBox)
  ' Convertir la imagen a escala de grises


  On Error Resume Next
  Dim grayscale As New Imaging.ColorMatrix(New Single()() _
  {
    New Single() {0.299, 0.299, 0.299, 0, 0},
    New Single() {0.587, 0.587, 0.587, 0, 0},
    New Single() {0.114, 0.114, 0.114, 0, 0},
    New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    New Single() {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
  })
  Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Imagen.Image)
  Dim imgattr As New Imaging.ImageAttributes()
  imgattr.SetColorMatrix(grayscale)
  Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    g.DrawImage(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
      0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height,
      GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgattr)
  End Using
  Imagen.Image = bmp
End Sub


Public Sub ConvertirAGrises33(ByVal Imagen As PictureBox)
  ' Convertir la imagen a escala de grises del 33% de cada color balanceada

  On Error Resume Next
  Dim grayscale As New Imaging.ColorMatrix(New Single()() _
  {
    New Single() {0.333, 0.333, 0.333, 0, 0},
    New Single() {0.333, 0.333, 0.333, 0, 0},
    New Single() {0.333, 0.333, 0.333, 0, 0},
    New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    New Single() {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
  })
  Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Imagen.Image)
  Dim imgattr As New Imaging.ImageAttributes()
  imgattr.SetColorMatrix(grayscale)
  Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    g.DrawImage(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
      0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height,
      GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgattr)
  End Using
  Imagen.Image = bmp
End Sub

Cómo pongo en comentarios, la diferencia esta en que la de 33 se coge desde iluminación pero la de 0.299 0.578 y 0.114 no entiendo porque se les da esos valores.
¿Alguien sabe el porque de la diferencia?

los diferentes coeficientes son para preservar la luminancia relativa de cada canal y que la imagen resultante tenga la misma luminancia absoluta.

Desconocía este contenido en la Wikipedia, Gracias por tu aporte.

Esto por lo que veo es bastante difícil de explicar, pero, por lo visto es por el entrelazado de luminosidad que hay entre colores grises y los colores rgb.
Así, doy por concluida la pregunta. Gracias.
